# Horizontal alignment of content in two different tabular rows

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I have a tabular table with all elements left-justified. Here is the MWE code followed by the output:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{lll}
  \toprule
  & $\alpha$ & $\beta$\\
  \midrule
  atomic $\text{C}$ & 1.1 & 2.2\\
  ($\text{C}_a$) & & \\ \addlinespace
  polymeric $\text{C}$ & 3.3 & 4.4\\
  ($\text{C}_p$) & & \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: table]

- I would like to align the **C** in **C_a** with the the **C** in "atomic C".
- I would also like to align the **C** in **C_p** with the **C** in "polymeric C".

In other words, indent C_a and C_b so that they align with the C immediately above.

Is this possible in a relatively simple way?

(In actuality, I am using the `chemmacros` package to typeset the **C**'s (e.g., `\ch{C}`), but to keep things simple in my MWE, I used `\text`. I think that the answer to this question, if one exists, will probably be independent of whether I use `\ch` or `\text`.)

Comment: Please make your example code compilable by adding the missing packages. Regarding your use of `\text` instead of `\ch` in your MWE: To be honest, I don't think, using `\text` for simplicity really helps here. For `\text` you need to load `amsmath`, for `\ch`, you also just need one package, so I can't realls see the simplicity here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution that employs the `\mathllap` macro of the `mathtools` package, which is a superset of the `amsmath` package, to facilitate the alignment of the `\ch{C}` elements.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemmacros,booktabs,mathtools}
\newcommand\myarray[2]{%
   $\begin{array}[t]{@{}l@{}} #1 \\ \mathllap{(}#2) \end{array}$}
\begin{document}
 
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{}lcc@{}}
  \toprule
  & $\alpha$ & $\beta$\\
  \midrule
  atomic \myarray{\ch{C}}{\ch{C}_a} & 1.1 & 2.2\\
  \addlinespace
  polymeric \myarray{\ch{C}}{\ch{C}_p} & 3.3 & 4.4\\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Here is a method using `\widthof` from the `calc` package in order to measure the required indentation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\usepackage{calc}

\newlength{\mylengthatomic}
\setlength{\mylengthatomic}{\widthof{atomic}-\widthof{(}}
\newlength{\mylengthpolymeric}
\setlength{\mylengthpolymeric}{\widthof{polymeric}-\widthof{(}}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{lll}
  \toprule
  & $\alpha$ & $\beta$\\
  \midrule
  atomic \ch{C}  & 1.1 & 2.2\\
  \hspace{\mylengthatomic} (\ch{C_a}) & & \\ \addlinespace
  polymeric \ch{C} & 3.3 & 4.4\\
  \hspace{\mylengthpolymeric} (\ch{C_p}) & & \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

The second example uses nested tabulars for the alignment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{chemmacros}


\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{lll}
  \toprule
  & $\alpha$ & $\beta$\\
  \midrule
  \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}\begin{tabular}[t]{ll} atomic & \phantom{(}\ch{C} \\ & (\ch{C_a})\end{tabular}  & 1.1 & 2.2\\ \addlinespace
  \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}\begin{tabular}[t]{ll} polymeric & \phantom{(}\ch{C} \\ & (\ch{C_p})\end{tabular} & 3.3 & 4.4\\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```